# ListView item setTextColor modified other elements

Tags: android, listview, text, colors, onclick

I have a ListView backed by SimpleCursorAdapter and custom ViewBinder. I want to make items in this listview change their color on clicking. If I do that in the OnClickListener - it works paritally, changing the color of the item clicked, and of the items down the list, each 7th (I guess, the period depends on on the viewable area of the listview).

Can anyone suggest how to deal with this? Or, maybe point to a more elegant way of making items in the listView selectable?

Thank you.

UPD: (sorry for bad formatting - this is the first time I post a question):

Below is how I try to make an item in the ListView "selected":

```
    private void setupListView(final ListView lv) {

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, final long id) {
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view;
                int color;
                if (conditionMet) {
                      color = R.color.gray;
                 } else {
                      color = R.color.red;
                 }

                 for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
((TextView)layout.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color)); 
    }

                 return;
            }}
```

This is how I init the adapter:

```
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        itemId,
                        cursor,
                        from,
                        to
                );
        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                final TextView textView = (TextView) view;
// do necessary conversions
                return true;
            }
        });
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: added a bit of code, any other part to add? Actually, as i said, this works partially, as it does "highlight" the item itself, but then its view is reused, I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no other answer, and, I think, I had some troubles with the suggestion below, I post how I did it:

1. I store ids of the items clicked in a special map
2. in the listview onclick I check whether the id of the just clicked item is in the map: if yes, I remove it and make the item and its children color A, otherwise I add the id to the map and set the color to B

   ```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, final long id) {
               Context ctx = MainActivity.this;
                   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view;
                   try {

                           int color;
                           if (items.containsKey(id)) {
                               items.remove(id);
                               color = R.color.gray;
                               tempIds.remove(id);
                           } else {
                               items.put(id, sum);
                               color = R.color.red;
                               tempIds.add(id);
                           }


                       for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                           final TextView textView = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(i);
                           textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color));
                       }
                   } catch (ParseException e) {
                       Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Exception parsing", e);
                   }
                   return;
               }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property [android:listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector) to set the theme or any drawable or color of the currently selected item in a list.